# Existence Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm reading through a proof of the existence of a Brownian motion and at some point they state that for $0\leq t_{0}<t_{1}...<t_{n}$ there exist multivariate normal distributions with covariance matrices
\begin{pmatrix}
t_{0} & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & t_{1}-t_{0} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & t_{2}-t_{1} & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & t_{n}-t_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}

and

\begin{pmatrix}
t_{0} & t_{0} & \cdots & \cdots & t_{0}\\
t_{0} & t_{1} & t_{1} & \cdots & t_{1}\\
t_{0} & t_{1} & t_{2} & \cdots & t_{2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t_{0} & t_{1} & t_{2} & \cdots & t_{n}
\end{pmatrix}

I think the proof of this involves Kolmogorov's consistency theorem but I cannot quite see/proof why there exist multivariate normal distributions with such covariances.
Could anyone help me see this?
Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kolmogorov's consistency theorem is not involved (and I am curious to know what gave you this idea). Rather one must either check that these matrices are symmetric definite nonnegative or realize some gaussian vectors with these covariance matrices from independent gaussian random vectors. Since both approaches are trivial in the first case, I am not sure about what is blocking you here.

Comment: Ok.. and why do I need to show that these matrices are symmetric definite nonnegative? Is there a theorem that states this result? I'm really quite confused as to how to go about understanding this.

Comment: [Yes there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties).

Comment: I understand that a Gaussian distribution has a symmetric nonnegative definite covariance matrix but why does a matrix of this form imply that there actually exists a Gaussian distribution with this covariance matrix. Any chance you could help me see this?

Comment: In other words, you are wondering [Which matrices are covariance matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Which_matrices_are_covariance_matrices.3F). Perhaps try to read the link I already gave you in my previous comment.

Comment: No Im sure all nonnegative definite matrices are covariance matrices but why to Gaussian distribution in particular in this case?

Comment: Quote from the page I linked to: *Let X be any p×1 column vector-valued random variable whose covariance matrix is the p×p identity matrix. Then...* End of quote. Note they say: ANY vector-valued random variable. Surely you can provide a suitable gaussian one?

Comment: I appreciate your patience with me. Thank you.